# How to debug “Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories” as the console output of font-manager?

Tags: fonts, fontconfig, debian-bookworm

Starting

```
font-manager
```

as a regular user from a console (regardless of the presence or the contents of /usr/local/share/fonts) prints four messages

```
Fontconfig error: No writable cache directories
```

on the console. /var/log/syslog and dmesg show nothing interesting, and running

```
fc-cache -r && fc-cache -fv && dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig fontconfig-cache font-manager
```

as root didn't help.

How to debug this error?

Comment: Try `sudo fc-cache`.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo font-manager`?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Upon `sudo font-manager`, these error messages don't appear. Are you implying that viewing fonts *should* be done as root?

Comment: Font manager can do more than *view* fonts. *Any* app that can make system changes certainly *should* require higher privilege.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Alright, then the error message is unactionable or has a wrong level of abstraction. Mildly put :-).